# imaging/cloning with DHCP network rebuilding/recovery of solaris 9 and 10 sparc servers

Tags: solaris, clone, sparc, jumpstart

I have a number of solaris 9 and 10 sparc servers (no RAID) that are custom dvd jumpstarts provided by SONUS Networks for their softswitch VOIP products.  Normal install process would be to use the DVD supplied by SONUS to do a reinstall from scratch in the event of failure.  Since we deploy our softswitches to unmanned locations having someone manually do a rebuild and reconfiguration of the servers is not the best.  We have out of bound access to the machines ALOMS so running commands from OpenBoot is not a problem.

i have looked at using puppet in combination with theforeman to provide network jumpstart installs and software configuration, but due to the way the custom SONUS DVDs were created a network jumpstart has been problematic and would require us to recreate the entire install process which would involve modifying the SONUS custom scripts which we don't feel comfortable doing.  The best solution to us would to image/clone a server and then in the event of a failure have the option to do a install of that image/clone from a local linux server.  Hopefully being able to leverge DHCP and NFS.

Any ideas would be very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris flash archives might be what you are looking for. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19683-01/816-7171/6md6pohot/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done installs like this in a long time, but we used to install one server and then ufsdump the root.  The install process would only need to network boot to single user, partition the disk, restore the dump file (which could be served by NFS) into the root partition, rebuild the device tree with drvconfig/disks/devfsadm, put in boot blocks with installboot, and then reboot under the new root.  It might have to do some fiddling with the vfstab if the path the disk device ends up different.  A lot of will depend on that vendor install, and if it does anything that can't be copied verbatim to another system.